# Xcode 9, Carthage. iTunes Connect Error: "Invalid Bundle - Disallowed LLVM instrumentation"

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, carthage, xcode9

Today I downloaded Xcode 9 and made the necessary changes for my application to compile. The application is compiling and running locally without any issues.

Using Xcode 9 I uploaded it to the App Store. Upload was successful without any errors.

I then go the following email from Apple:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "KiteSpotter - Kitesurf wind and weather forecast". To process your
>   delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
>
> Invalid Bundle - Disallowed LLVM instrumentation. Do not submit apps
>   with LLVM profiling instrumentation or coverage collection enabled.
>   Turn off LLVM profiling or code coverage, rebuild your app and
>   resubmit the app.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the
>   corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

I went and turned off code coverage for both my target and cocoa pods target, which was the only relevant setting I could find:

[image]

Resubmitted the application and I am getting the same error.

On my project I am using Carthage, which has more than 15 dependencies. Searching for a solution I found that all projects need to be updated with the above setting.

- Is there any solution to automate this setting for all frameworks, if that is causing the problem.
- Has anyone else faced this problem and sorted it out. Were the Carthage frameworks creating the issue or something else?

Comment: This is also discussed here: https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/2056

Comment: As https://github.com/frankschlegel said you can use the following command to find the frameworks that are causing this "grep -R "codeCoverageEnabled" Carthage"

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The solution to automate setting code coverage to false for all dependencies is to run the following command on terminal (please go to the directory of your project):

```
grep -lR "codeCoverageEnabled" --include *.xcscheme --null Carthage | xargs -0 sed -i '' -e 's/codeCoverageEnabled = "YES"/codeCoverageEnabled = "NO"/g'
```

This will set code coverage to NO and iTunes connect will not complain.

The sequence to make everything work is the following

- Run `carthage update --platform iOS --no-use-binaries --no-build`. This will update and download all dependecies.
  When Carthage start to compile you can press ctrl+c to cancel.
- Run the above command to set code coverage to NO
- Now that everything is into place run `carthage build --platform iOS`. This will build everything with code coverage to NO

You can now archive and upload to iTC.

The command was given by https://github.com/gunterhager, so credit goes to him

---

As an alternative for **fastlane users**, add the following to your fastlane file, which will automate everything:

```
  desc "Update Carthage"
  lane :update_carthage do
    carthage(
      command: "update",       # One of: build, bootstrap, update, archive. (default: bootstrap)
      use_binaries: false,         # Check out dependency repositories even when prebuilt frameworks exist
      no_build: true,  # When bootstrapping Carthage do not build
      platform: "iOS"  # Define which platform to build for (one of ‘all’, ‘Mac’, ‘iOS’, ‘watchOS’, ‘tvOS‘, or comma-separated values of the formers except for ‘all’)
    )
    sh("grep -lR 'codeCoverageEnabled' --include *.xcscheme --null Carthage | xargs -0 sed -i '' -e 's/codeCoverageEnabled = 'YES'/codeCoverageEnabled = 'NO'/g'")
    carthage(
      command: "build",       # One of: build, bootstrap, update, archive. (default: bootstrap)
      platform: "iOS"  # Define which platform to build for (one of ‘all’, ‘Mac’, ‘iOS’, ‘watchOS’, ‘tvOS‘, or comma-separated values of the formers except for ‘all’)
    )
  end
```

Comment: If you don't have the GNU command line installed like me, you can use this:

find Carthage -type f -name "*.xcscheme" -print0 | xargs -0 perl -pi -e 's/codeCoverageEnabled = "YES"/codeCoverageEnabled = "NO"/g'

Answer (score 13):

As quick fix, run these commands in Terminal (be sure to go to your project's root folder):

- `carthage update --platform iOS --no-use-binaries --no-build` This will update your dependencies, but will build nothing.
- `grep -lR "codeCoverageEnabled" --include *.xcscheme --null Carthage | xargs -0 sed -i '' -e 's/codeCoverageEnabled = "YES"/codeCoverageEnabled = "NO"/g'` This will set code coverage to `NO`.
- `carthage build --platform iOS` This will finally build all frameworks without code coverage.

Now you can archive your project and upload it to iTunes Connect.

The nice people at the `Carthage` project are already working on a more user friendly fix, so be sure to check for releases there.

Comment: This pretty much repeats @zirinisp's answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, i couldn't comment on @zirinisp's answer: i'm the one he refers to, and i wanted to point out that you should use `--no-build` for the `carthage update`.

Comment: @GunterHager. I can see you are new here, so I would like to give you a warm welcome. The correct thing to do in that case, would be to edit my answer and improve it or add a comment and I would improved it like I did. In any case your commands has helped me out a lot.

Comment: This answer is easier to follow than the accepted answer because the steps are in order.

Answer (score 3):

Just update `Carthage` to version `0.26.0` or higher and then run the `carthage update` command again.

Answer (score 3):

I too got same error from Xcode 9.1 even though I have updated Carthage to latest version https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/releases I have failed in uploading build to iTunes

[image]

**Worked for me this way:-**

If you have updated your **Xcode to 9.1** then

Update your `carthage.pkg` downloading from https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/releases

Install `.pkg` and

Give `carthage update` command in `Terminal` by referring to your project

and

then go to you project `Build Settings` find `Enable Code Coverage Support` change that setting from **`Yes`** to **`No`**

[image]

Then Archive and upload to `AppStore`. You build will be `ready`. `Happy`!

[image]