# How to disable LLVM Code Coverage in Fabric Crashlytics

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

On submitting an iOS app to the Apple App Store recently, I'm receiving the following error during processing of the build:

> Invalid Bundle - Disallowed LLVM instrumentation. Do not submit apps
>   with LLVM profiling instrumentation or coverage collection enabled.
>   Turn off LLVM profiling or code coverage, rebuild your app and
>   resubmit the app.

Searching Stack Overflow, the solution is to disable LLVM Code Coverage in all dependencies. I have done this for all open source Carthage dependencies, but I'm still getting the error message. I believe this is because the Fabric and Crashlytics dependencies in the project have LLVM Code Coverage enabled, but I cannot disable this as I only have access to the .framework files, and not the .xcodeproj files.

How can I change the LLVM Code Coverage build setting for Fabric / Crashlytics?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Are you copying or linking our frameworks in?

Comment: Linking I believe, I installed them following the steps in Fabric.app for Mac, and they're in the `Linked Frameworks and Binaries` build phase.

Comment: You might try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46226810/3975963

Comment: That's the one I've tried, but it only works for open source Carthage modules as it changes the .xcodeproj / .xcscheme files. With Fabric we can only see the .framework files right?

Answer (score 1):

In our case Fabric frameworks were not the cause of the mentioned error.

Apple suggest to run the following scripts on your archive (output of Xcode archive operation):

`nm -m -arch all <PathToArchive>/Products/Applications/<AppName>.app/<AppBinary> | grep gcov`

`otool -l -arch all <PathToArchive>/Products/Applications/<AppName>.app/<AppBinary> | grep __llvm_prf`

But you can modify the path to target 'Frameworks' directory instead of the app binary and it will print out the frameworks with enabled instrumentation.

More info is available at [Resolving App Rejections for GCC and LLVM Instrumentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1964/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017675-CH1-SOURCECODE2).